# how to sign out of vimeo in iOS

Tags: ios, vimeo

In my app i am using Vimeo advanced api and retrieving the videos and other user details, every thing is good, but is there way to sign out api for Vimeo so that the user can sign out and another user can sign in. Is there any other technique to achieve that.

Comment: you cannot use multiple accounts with native vimeo.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam ok, is there any api like videos.getAll to perform signout of the user by calling a method

Comment: u can use Vimeo's OAUTH API for managing multiple logins

Answer (score 0):

With the Advanced API, all authentication is stateless. The token you provide defines the user you have authenticated as.

There is no concept of "logging out" a user because technically a user is never "logged in" for more than one request.

If you wish to allow a different user to log in, simply stop sending the old access token and request one for a different user.